# Vim: map-<window> equivalent?

Tags: vim

Vim's `wrap` option is local to the window, not buffer and if I would like to have a buffer specific map I can do that via `map-<buffer>`.

So putting the two together, if I want a wrap-mode specific mapping, how can I achieve `map-<window>` functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such a thing as "`map-<window>`". What is a "wrap-mode specific mapping"?

Comment: If I enable `wrap` in a window, I would like a way to build a mapping that would be exclusive to the wrap-enabled window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a window can display different buffers at various times, it doesn't make sense to have window-local mappings.

I think what you're really asking for is how to do different things in a mapping depending on a window-local setting like `'wrap'`. You can access the local `'wrap'` setting via the `&l:wrap` special variable, like in this example:

```
:nnoremap <expr> j &l:wrap ? 'gj' : 'j'
```

Comment: Thanks - but how would the nnoremap work if `'gj'` is `'<Plug>CustomMapping'`?

Comment: But would that make j recursive when not in wrap mode?

Comment: Try it, or read `:help mapping_recursive`. Alternatively, you could always use another `:noremap`'ped <Plug> mapping to avoid recursion.